# How to only detect a response less than a certain number

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been having trouble with my gamble command on my discord bot. I want to know how to detect only a response that's less than a specified number. I  have tried a few things. Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def gamble(ctx):
  def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel # New check
  
  
  
  users = await get_bank_data()
  
  user = ctx.author 
  embed42=discord.Embed(title='I Have chosen a number between 1 and 1000', description='if you guesse under my number you get to keep the number u guessed but if you guessed over than you lose the money you geussed and if you geusse the exact number you get $10000!', color=0xbbe3f3)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed42)

  row = random.randint(1,1000)

  response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check) # Wait for MESSAGE, add check
  if response.content == row:
    embed50 = discord.Embed(title='You Guessed ***on the dot***', description='You just got $10000')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed50)
    earniner = 10000
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earniner
    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
      json.dump(users,f)
      return True
  if response.content == response >= row:
    embed78 = discord.Embed(title='You Guessed **OVER**!', description=f'You just lost {ctx.message.content}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed78)
    earninga = response
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= earninga
    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
      json.dump(users,f)
      return True
  if response.content == response <= row:
    embed78 = discord.Embed(title='You Guessed *under*!', description=f'You just got {ctx.message.content}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed78)
    earninga = response
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earninga
    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
      json.dump(users,f)
      return True
```

i have tried a couple of things as i said but i just cannot figure it out, hopefully someone can spread some thoughts about my issue. thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you want? That your bot only listens to numbers below that specified number?

Comment: yes @Chuaat i want it to listen to numbers below that specified number.

Comment: Could you specify what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in check function. I also recommend checking with the id instead of the user himself for some reason.

```
def check(m):
    if m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.message.channel.id:
        if m.content.isdigit(): #check message's content is a integer
            if int(m.content) > 50: #checking the content is greater then 50
                return True
    return False
```